# Building boost with different gcc version

Tags: gcc, boost, build

I have access to server where I need to build boost 1.46. How can I force bootstrap.sh to use /usr/bin/gcc-4.4. By default it uses /usr/bin/gcc and I can't figure out how to change this

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I cross built Boost for an ARM toolchain using something like this:

```
echo "using gcc : arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi : /usr/local/arm/bin/g++ ; " >> tools/build/v2/user-config.jam
```

You should be able to do something like this:

*boost version 1.59 and above:*

```
echo "using gcc : 4.4 : /usr/bin/g++-4.4 ; " >> tools/build/src/user-config.jam
```

*boost version 1.58 and below:*

```
echo "using gcc : 4.4 : /usr/bin/g++-4.4 ; " >> tools/build/v2/user-config.jam
```

and then build with

```
bjam --toolset=gcc-4.4
```

Comment: Another confirmation: Linux Mint 17.1, x64, GCC-4.1, Boost 1.43

Comment: You may need a `./` on `./bjam` if you're building locally and you already have a system installation of Boost.

Comment: Why `bjam` rather than `b2`?

Comment: BTW: Be care for the **space**! missing space gives an error!

Comment: This implies that bjam somehow already exists.

Answer (score 3):

With the most recent version of Boost 1.71 works the below way:

```
>export CC=<path to custom gcc>/gcc
>export CXX=<path to custom gcc>/g++
>./bootstrap.sh
>./b2 --toolset=gcc stage threading=multi link=shared
```

You could check the gcc version used for build with bellow command

```
>ldd b2
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcaa5f4000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => <path to custom gcc>/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b85ab701000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b85abaaa000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => <path to custom gcc>/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b85abdac000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b85abfc3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b85ab4dd000)
```

or in bin.v2/project-cache.jam file

Comment: only b2 is built with the specified gcc, not the boost library

Comment: both `CC` and `CXX` are ignored by `./bootstrap.sh`

Answer (score 2):

*Update for Boost 1.59*

Now you need to do this:

```
echo "using gcc : : /usr/bin/g++44 ; " >> tools/build/src/user-config.jam
```

Answer (score 1):

For people who like to know the answer for Boost 1.61 on OSX 10.11.6: Sean's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346531/2535529) did not work for me because of the `ld: unknown option: -h` error mentioned in [this boost report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9306). To make it work I replaced `gcc` by `darwin` in his command

```
echo "using darwin : 6.2 : /usr/local/bin/g++-6 ; " >> tools/build/src/user-config.jam
```

To compile and install it I used

```
./b2 --toolset=darwin-6.2 --prefix=$HOME/.local/ install
```