# NAOqi library to python sdk in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am unable to run import naoqi as it gives error. It shows no such modules found. After troubleshooting I get path/to/python-sdk. But after that also it gives error and does not work. Please help with step by step solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Dependencies]: Python 2.7, boost library 1.55

[Boost 1.55] [ATTENTION: has to be Built with gcc 4.8. So install it in case you do not have it.]

- Download Boost 1.55 boost_1_55_0.tar.bz2 from [here](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html)
- Extract:
  `$ tar --bzip2 -xf boost_1_55.tar.gz2`
- As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346454/building-boost-with-different-gcc-version) you have to modify "boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/user-config.jam":
  `$ echo "using gcc : 4.8 g++-4.8 ; " >> tools/build/src/user-config.jam`
- Choose where you want to install the library and run:
  `$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/path/to/installation`
- Build and install:
  `$ ./b2 --toolset=gcc-4.8 install`
- Add installation directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
  `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/path/to/installation`

---

[Naoqi Python SDK]

- Choose a directory and extract pynaoqi-python-2.7-naoqi-x.x-linux64.tar.gz in it.
- Set the corresponding environmental variables:
  `$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/naoqi/python/sdk`
  `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/naoqi/python/sdk`
- Check if everything went well. Open a python terminal (python, ipython, etc) and run:
  `import naoqi`
- If you get no error, then you are ready to go.

---

cheers!